# Grep Value as Number after "Total :"

Tags: grep

I have lines in my log file like "*...- Total Speed: 118.604 Mh/s, Total Shares: 5....*"

How can I grep the last 3 "Total Speed" number values?

I tried the following command: `grep 'Total Speed: ' screenlog.0 | sed 's/^.*: //'` without success.

output should looks like :

118.604

118.604

118.604

Comment: please [edit] your question and provide a sample of full 2 lines which holds the pattern you would like us to manipulate.

Comment: not understand well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this simple use of `cut` and `grep` command:

```
cut -d: -f 2 mycut.txt | grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]{3}\.[[:digit:]]{3}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `awk` since the field number is fixed.

```
awk '/Speed:/ {print $3}' screenlog.0
```

The `$3` is the number of column. You did not give the full string, so you may need to change this number.

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ echo "Total Speed: 118.604 Mh/s, Total Shares: 5...." | awk '/Speed:/ {print $3}'
118.604
```

This will give you all the lines, not the last 3. You can use `tail -n3` to filter the last 3 lines:

```
tail -n3 screenlog.0 | awk '/Speed:/ {print $3}'
```

Comment: OP's input sample is used dots `... xy...` at first and end, awk doesn't grantee it's always in 3rd field thought or even in different fields in different lines

Comment: I wrote that in my answer. I don't think that fields vary in the log. Your solution is more universal, but in most cases fields numbers don't change.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grep` with [look-behind and look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) enablers of PCRE in `grep` as follows:

```
tail -n3 in.txt | grep -Pzo '(?<=Total Speed: ).*?(?=Mh/s)'
```

```
118.604
118.604
118.604
```

Or in short, you can use `\K` notify inplace of `lookbehind`:

```
grep -Pzo "Total Speed: \K.*(?=Mh/s)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Po 'Total Speed:\s*\K\d\S*' in.txt | tail -n 3
```